# Javascript Closure called automatically vs manually

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm confused between these two closure functions.

The doSomeMath returns the function without executing it when I assigned it to a variable, test. It will only run the closure function when I do test();
However this is not the case for showName function. As soon as I pass in the values, it calls the closure function right away instead of returning it.

Can someone kindly explain it to me? Thanks.

```
function showName (firstName, lastName) {
    var nameIntro = "Your name is ";
    // this inner function has access to the outer function's variables, including the parameter
    function makeFullName () {     
        var full = nameIntro + firstName + " " + lastName; 
        return full;   
    }

    return makeFullName ();
}

showName ("Michael", "Jackson"); // Your name is Michael Jackson


function doSomeMath(a, b) {
    var a = a;
    var b = b;

    function multiply() {
        var result = a * b;
        return result;
    }

    return multiply;
}

var test = doSomeMath(5,10);
test();
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - it's exactly as you said. One of them returns a function, and the other returns a value (the result of an immediately called function).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes. Why is that so? The first returns the value right away while second one returns a function

Comment: `return makeFullName ();` vs `return multiply;`. You can see that the first one is being called, while the second is not. (but you should format that better - function names should be right next to their parentheses)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh my god! I looked over the code over and over again and didn't notice that. Thank you!!

Comment: You might want to read about [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

These two functions are two different ways of demonstrating how closures work.

You could as easily have done the opposite to achieve the same effect.

```
function doSomeMath(a, b) {
    var a = a;
    var b = b;

    function multiply() {
        var result = a * b;
        return result;
    }

    return multiply();
}

doSomeMath(5,10) //50
```

In the above code you return the result of invocation of the inner function instead of the function itself. Here, as you can see, `multiply` has a closure over 5 and 10 and so you get the outcome as 50.

Similarly, try:

```
function showName (firstName, lastName) {
    var nameIntro = "Your name is ";
    // this inner function has access to the outer function's variables, including the parameter
    function makeFullName () {     
        var full = nameIntro + firstName + " " + lastName; 
        return full;   
    }

    return makeFullName;
}

var show = showName ("Michael", "Jackson");
show() //"Your name is Michael Jackson"
```

The above code returns the inner function instead of its invocation and in turn demonstrates how the inner function, `makeFullName` has a closure over the `nameIntro` variable of the outer function.

The other answer provides a concise understanding on closures. To know more read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to understand the above examples better.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing closures and higher order functions.

There is no such concept as manually calling a function. A function must always be called. This does not change if the function is a closure.

In fact one might say that this is the essential power of closures as an abstraction mechanism.

A closure is a function that references elements in its enclosing scope.

This is often referred to as lexical scoping.

The set of elements of the enclosing scope that are referenced by a closure are known as its environment.

A function that does not refer to elements in its enclosing scope can be thought of as a degenerate closure - a closure with an empty environment.

The value returned by a function may be another function but this is purely orthogonal to the notion of closures.

In JavaScript, as in many languages, functions are first class values. This means that they can be stored in variables, passed as arguments, and returned as results.

Consider

```
var createIncrement = function (incrementBy) {
  return function (value) {
    return value + incrementBy;
  };
};
```

The function above is higher order, because it returns a function. *Incidentally*, it is *also* a closure because it references `incrementBy` which is declared in an enclosing scope.

The confusion expressed in the framing of your question likely arises from the fact that, in practice, the two features will be used together in even the simplest of JavaScript programs.